# How to control the paging item limit for my discussions inside a community site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, 2013, community

I have a community site , but I am unable to figure out how to control the paging item limits for the following views ; Recent, What's hot & My discussions. I tried for example to modify the item limit for a view named “Recent Changes ” but it did not change anything ?

So where to control the paging item limit?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In these situations, the view is sometimes specific to the web part displaying it, so you want to go to the page with the web part and select the "Modify View" option from there. Its its SP2010, you'll want to click on some part of the list within the web part to get the context specific "List" menu tab to show up in the ribbon, then go to "Modify View."